# Atom Editor: how to highlight singe and double quote strings differently for php

Tags: php, atom-editor

I recently installed Clear Linux and their default is Atom editor, so I gave it a try. With the php-autocomplete, I was almost very excited. Until I realized I have become set in my ways and I need to have different highlighting for single vs double quote strings.

In `php` double quoted strings will still be parsed for `$variables` and whitespace escape characters like `\n` and `\t`; whereas single quoted strings are literal and there is no interpretation between single quotes.

I have developed the habit of always using single quotes for array keys and it disturbed my subconscious to not have the single quoted strings appear different than double quoted strings. I searched quite a bit and couldn't find a solution.

**Does anyone know of a way to achieve this highlighting scheme?**

The screenshot is from Geany. And even in Geany, getting this setting is not standard. Thankfully, a decade ago, this was normal in their themes so I am able to alter the currently available themes to find and change `string_2` to a different color than `string_2=string_1`.

To better help people understand `php` and how the differences between `'` and `"` may have importance, here is one way the strings behave differently in context:

```php
    $customer = "Bill Hawthorne";
    $_address = "123 Main St\nGlendale, CA 91202";

    $output = "Dear $customer, please confirm the below address is correct:\n\n$_address\n";

    // $output renders as:
    // Dear Bill Waltz, please confirm the below address is correct:
    //
    // 123 Main St
    // Glendale, CA 91202
    // 

    $output = 'Dear $customer, please confirm the below address is correct:\n\n$_address\n';
    // $output renders as:
    // Dear $customer, please confirm the below address is correct:\n\n$_address\n
```

[image: screenshot of Geany editor showing different highlight colors for php strings of type single quote and double quote]

Comment: but.. a string = a string, regardless of quotes., (also.. you're open to SQL injection from the look of things..) - probably have to code something for this.. besides, it's never good to mix quotes anyway, just have single quotes IMO. Unless you prefer less readability and/or need to use \n (even then. PHP_EOL exists)

Comment: Please don't distract from the issue. This code is not public facing. And strings are not strings: Having `$variables` interpreted inside of "Injector $inj_label is good" will result in `Injector DX is good`, whereas 'Injector $inj_label is good' shows as `Injector $inj_label is good`. As far as I can tell, those two rendered outputs are not the same.

Comment: I'm using PHPStorm and agree strings are strings. What I see is the highlighting on the variable in `"Injector $inj_label is good"` (your dark purple), and not `'Injector $inj_label is good'` which is what matters most to me. I can clearly see if it is parsed or a literal. I'd actually appreciate having what you describe though, it would just help me be more consistent, array keys, etc.

Comment: @treyBake you are factually incorrect. `php` will interpret inside the double quotes for a comparison. If there is a `$string` variable set, `'$string' != "$string"`

Comment: @ChrisK which is what my comment literally says. It's still a string, it's just a string that parses what's inside, which is why they're slower. But for whatever reason, my comment was removed? We're talking about var types here - not content. https://phpfiddle.tk/55b8bde1

Comment: just as a general query - what happens if you do `echo 'hello'` in that editor with the different-quote highlighting? I notice that the single quotes seem to be only used for array keys.. I wonder if they have some regex to do `$var[]` and highlight the key.. would it still highlight the same if it was double quotes? (as in, is it still yellow with double quotes for array keys)

Comment: @treyBake there isn't any added level of regex or matching; as mine is setup `'hello'` will appear yellow. When you open a `'` or `"`, the entire document until the next quote changes to that string type's highlight color. This makes it quite obvious when you forget a quote, too. I chose this code for example to better demonstrate the question. I really tried to give Atom a go, but it tripped me up too much. I'm strict about using `'literals'` where one must not consider it a string and then `"strings`" everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `Editor: Log cursor scope` in the command palette to see the scope applied to a section of text. This scope is applied to the text in the DOM, with `syntax--` prepended to each segment.

In the case of `language-php`, the scope is `string.quoted.double.php` for double quoted strings, and `string.quoted.single.php` for single quoted. The following is an example of how you might target them. Note this part is pure CSS / Less; I don't really know it well, so it may be possible to be more concise here.

```
// ~/.atom/styles.less
atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text html php"] { // target PHP
  .syntax--string.syntax--quoted {
    &.syntax--double,
    &.syntax--double .syntax--punctuation.syntax--definition.syntax--string { // get the quote chars too
      color: red;
    }

    &.syntax--single,
    &.syntax--single .syntax--punctuation.syntax--definition.syntax--string {
      color: yellow;
    }
  }
}
```

E.g., try it with this `<?php "foo $bar" ?>`.

Comment: I did `View->Toggle Command Palette` and it said command not found about the editor input.